Merge CSV rows backfilling the empty rows
I have a large CSV file with many columns that has mostly repetitive values but some columns with changing values from row to row. These changing columns either have data in them or are empty. Other columns have fixed values (see example below). How can I compress or remove duplicate rows such that the empty lines are merged into fewer lines? I have written a Python script that does this but it feels like there should be some elegant Linux command line way to do this in one go.
Sample CSV input:



Fixed Col 1
Fixed Col 2
Variable Col 3
Variable Col 4




A
B

1


A
B
1



C
D
1



C
D

1



The expected output is:



Fixed Col 1
Fixed Col 2
Variable Col 3
Variable Col 4




A
B
1
1


C
D
1
1



Notice how the first two columns have fixed data while the other two have empty or data values. Merging the lines essentially fills in the empty columns while keeping the fixed columns the same.

Something like this awk-script:
awk -F "\t" 'BEGIN{ OFS="\t"; getline }{ a3[$1FS$2]+=$3; a4[$1FS$2]+=$4 }END{ for( i in a3){  print i,a3[i],a4[i]} }' input

output:
C       D       1       1
A       B       1       1

You have to solve the missing headers yourself (sorry, no time to add them) 
